# How to store data into different storage mediums in starrocks data shared mode?

Tags: starrocks

I am using starrocks 3.1.4 data shared mode. And I have a table that is too large to store in one single disk. I find this in the documentation [image]

So for example If I have two different object storage service on two different server s3-1 and s3-2. Is that possible that I can store the data (from one table) into this two s3 services separately? And how can I achieve this because I didn't find any demo or examples in the documentation.

Or if it doesn't works can anyone tell me how should I solve the issue of a StarRocks(data shared mode) table becoming too large to store on a single disk? Thanks!!

Comment: I'd ask this in starrocks community slack.